# Hibernate @Temporal for Java 8 java.time.Instant

Tags: hibernate, jpa, java-8

I use Hibernate and try to do the following:

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@Column(name = "BIRTHDAY")
private Instant birthday;
```

but have this exception:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @Temporal should only be set on a java.util.Date or java.util.Calendar property:
```

As was suggested I tried to use

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-java8</artifactId>
    <version>${hibernate.ver}</version>
</dependency>
```

but have the same exception. Should I do some additional steps or how to resolve such a case?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can not use `@Temporal` with java 8 time, if you want date with time use `LocalDateTime`, if you want only date use `LocalDate` without `@Temporal` anotation.

look also http://www.thoughts-on-java.org/persist-localdate-localdatetime-jpa/

Comment: Thank you, actualy I've found solution described in second part of article by your link (with converter) and used it - it works fine!

Comment: @DmitriiAdonin, the only thing you need is to remove the annotation and mark the field as a basic column. Works fine without need of any converter. I does not comes straight from the answer, so HAYMbl4 would you please edit your answer?

Answer (score 19):

Java 8 Date and time API is supported by JPA 2.2 using the columnDefinition:

```
@Column(name = "local_time", columnDefinition = "TIME")
private LocalTime localTime;

@Column(name = "local_date", columnDefinition = "DATE")
private LocalDate localDate;

@Column(name = "local_date_time", columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP")
private LocalDateTime localDateTime;
```

Comment: It is a wrong solution. You need to skip `columnDefinition` field. Automatically the corrent type will be applied. Not all databases have `TIME` type. For instance - Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

Since JPA 2.2, `java.time` fields are supported.
But the `@Temporal` annotation does not support them (as of [JPA 3.0](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/persistence/3.0/jakarta-persistence-spec-3.0.pdf)).