# Create column type Datetime in Hibernate for LocalDateTime

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

What is the proper way to create column type Datetime in MariaDB using JPA? I tried this:

```
@Column
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private LocalDateTime created_at;
```

But I get exception:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @Temporal should only be set on a java.util.Date or java.util.Calendar property: org.plugin.entity.Transactions.created_at
```

Can you propose some solution?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hibernate @Temporal for Java 8 java.time.Instant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35507985/hibernate-temporal-for-java-8-java-time-instant)

Answer (score 2):

You have the `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` dependency which has `hibernate-core` as a compile dependency.

If you are using spring boot 1.4.x or higher you get Hibernate 5:

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa/1.4.0.RELEASE

The you just have to add the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-java8</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

which provides support for Java 8 LocalDateTime API.

If you are using Spring boot version 2.x.x or higher `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` ships with hibernate 5.2 which has Java 8 LocalDateTime API build in so no additional dependencies are necessary.

You can simply write:

```
private LocalDateTime created_at;
```

Comment: I use `<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>`

Comment: Then the Temporal annotation nor additional dependencies are needed.

Comment: What declaration for column type should I use?

Comment: You don't need the `@Temporal` annotation. Any required conversion, if necessary, will be done by hibernate itself.

Comment: If the table column name matches the object property name you don't even need the `@Column` annotation. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22735543/column-annotation-absolutly-necessary-in-jpa Just write it as I wrote it in the answer. No annotations necessary.

Comment: Unfortunately after package deployment column type is updated to DATE. It should be DATETIME. Looks like I need other way to configure Entity

Answer (score 0):

Update version of Hibernate to 5.x or latest, there is

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-java8</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

You don't have to do anything else. Just add the dependency. Of course other Java8 types should also work.

```
private LocalDateTime created_at;
```

Comment: I use JPA. These are my POM dependencies: https://pastebin.com/seEYBsMd

Comment: can you recommend some solution for JPA?